# Determine the sum of the entries in the main diagonal of the matrix $A · A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, transpose

All the entries of the matrix A are $0$, $1$ or $-1$, and it has exactly $2012$ nonzero entries.
Determine the sum of the entries in the main diagonal of the matrix $A · A^T$

I can only figure out that $A · A^T$ is symmetric matrix but I don't know how I can use this property?

UPDATE: I have not satisfied with given answers.The question is still active there is no accepted answer.

Comment: Sum of entries of main diagonal is called the trace.

Comment: 2012 non zero entries is confusing to me

Comment: @AnuragA it is not given

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the sum of all diagonal entries of $AA^T$ is equal to $\sum_i\sum_j(A)_{ij}(A^T)_{ji}=\sum_i\sum_jA_{ij}^2$ (we usually write this as $\operatorname{tr}(AA^T)=\|A\|_F^2$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_norm)). Since $A_{ij}\in\{0,1,-1\}$, $A_{ij}^2$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: but we need to determine sum so we need to now it 0 or 1

Comment: @subhanceo With the information given, we know that there are $2012$ terms in the sum not equal to zero

Comment: I didnt understand how you come conclusion that $ AA^T $ equals to that

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A=[a_{ij}]\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $. Then, $A^T=[b_{ij}]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $a_{ij}=b_{ji}$ for each $i,j$. We have that $A\cdot A^T\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, and therefore
$$tr(A\cdot A^T)=\sum_{i=1}^m \:c_{ii}$$
where $A\cdot A^T=[c_{ij}]$. The matrix multiplication formula yields
$$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n \:a_{ik}\cdot b_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^n \:a_{ik}\cdot a_{jk}$$
Putting $i=j$ and summing over $i$ gives
$$tr(A\cdot A^T)=\sum_{i=1}^m \:c_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n\: a_{ik}^2=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2$$

Since $a_{ij}\in\{-1,0,1\}$ and $A$ has $2012$ non-zero entries by hypothesis, we have
$$\boxed{tr(A\cdot A^T)=2012}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a_k$ is the $k-$th row of $A$, then
$$
(AA^T)_{kk}=a_k\cdot a_k=\|a_k\|^2=\text{number of non-zero elements}
$$
But
$$
\|a_k\|^2=\text{number of non-zero elements of $a_k$}
$$
Hence
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\,(AA^T)=\sum_{k=1}^n (AA^T)_{kk}=\sum_{k=1}^n \|a_k\|^2=\text{number of nonzero elements of $A$}=2012
$$

Comment: what is $ a_{k}$